# what is causing my font-size to be so small?

Tags: html-table, html-email, font-size

I'm coding an email for my employer. The `font-size` *should* be 16px. I declared it in `table td`, but it's being overwritten somewhere. I absolutely cannot figure out how or why. Has anyone else run into this issue?

Edit: I should specify that the undesired font-size is occurring on mobile only:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
  <title>Title</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400,300,700);
body {
  width: 100% !important;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#background_table {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%!important;
  line-height: 100%!important;
}

img {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

table td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Trebuchet, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px!important;
  line-height:120%;
  color: #000;
}

table td[class="column"] {
  height: 100px;
  width: 640px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
  mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
}

table[class="body_table"] {
  width: 640px;
  margin-top: 21px;
}

table span[class="h1"] {
  font-weight:300;
  font-size:23px;
  color:#ff9001;
}

table td[class="top-buffer"] {
  padding-top: 25px;
}
  </style>


</head>

<body>

  <!-- background table start -->
  <table width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="background_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <!-- end of background table start -->
          <table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="display:inline-block;" width="100%"><img src="#" alt="Logo" style="display:block;">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="100%" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="100%" height="100">
                  <img src="#" alt="Hero" style="display:block;">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="100%" height="10">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <!-- hello/quick links -->
          <table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td width="640" class="column" style="height:100%;font-size:20px;">Hello,

                  <br> Content
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="10">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="640" class="column" style="padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:20px;">
                  <span class="h1">Quick Links</span>
                  <br>

                  <span style="display:inline-block; padding-bottom:5px;"><strong><a href="#" target="_blank">LE Brochure 14min</a></strong></span>
                  <br> Got a booth at a trade show or event? This video can be set to play continuously to draw more attention and foot traffic.
                  <br>
                  <br>
                  <span style="display:inline-block; padding-bottom:5px;"><strong>FedEx Flyer Link</strong></span>
                  <br> Customizable seasonal flyers available
                  <br><a href="#" target="_blank">FedEx Product Service Gateway</a>
                  <br>
                  <br>
                  <span style="display:inline-block; padding-bottom:5px;"><strong>Marketing Bulletin Archive</strong></span>
                  <br><a href="#">Intranet</a>

                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <!-- hello/quick links -->
          <br>
          <!-- marketing communications -->
          <table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <span class="h1">Marketing Communications</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="148" class="column-img" style="height:100%;display:inline-block;margin-right:17px">
                <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" style="display:block;"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td width="503" class="column-text-1"><span style="font-size:18px;display:inline-block; padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:5px;">
                <strong>Top Video Testimonials</strong></span>
                  <br> Four 90-second videos now in our Resource Center with tips from families to families. <a href="#" target="_blank">Click here to view.</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <!-- marketing communications -->
          <br>
          <!-- new print collateral -->
          <table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="top-buffer">
                  <span class="h1">New Print Collateral</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td width="148" class="column-img" style="height:100%;display:inline-block;margin-right:17px">
                  <img src="#" style="display:block;">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="503" class="column-text-1"><span style="font-size:18px;display:inline-block; padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:5px;"><strong>New for events and booths: Women & Alzheimer’s 24x36 foam board poster</strong></span>
                  <br> Now avaiblable on our <a href="#" target="_blank">FedEx Product Service Gateway.</a> SKU1450. You can find this 24x36 poster under Programs/Women and Alzheimer’s. Here’s an informative story
                  from <a href="#" target="_blank">The Washington Post</a> for more
                  background on why women get Alzheimer’s more than men and who is more at risk.
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <!-- new print collateral -->
          <br>
          <!-- advertising -->
          <!-- brand ads -->
          <table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="top-buffer">
                  <span class="h1" style="display:inline-block;">Advertising</span>
                  <br>
                  <span style="font-size:18px;">
                <table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <span style="font-size:18px;"><strong>Brand Ads Spring/Summer 2015</strong></span>
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td width="350" class="column" style="height:100%;margin-right:131px">
                  <img src="#">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="350" height="10">
                  &nbsp;
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="height:100%;" width="350" class="column">
                  <img src="#">
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- brand ads -->

  <!-- community ads -->
  <table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-top:30px;padding-bottom:10px;">
          <span style="font-size:18px;"><strong>Community Event Ads Getting Results</strong></span>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td width="350" class="column" style="height:100%;margin-right:131px">
          <img src="#" style="min-width:350px; display:block">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td width="350" style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:40px;">
                  Over 100 attended this Pleasant Hill film critic event. General Manger Aubrey Goo says, “The ads definitely helped.”
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height:100%;" width="350" class="column"><img src="#" style="min-width:350px;display:block">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td width="350" style="padding-top:10px">
                  <br> This Moraga Dementia speaker event is dubbed a success. Marketing Director Nancy Moraga says, “This event was successful because we stuck to the basics in helping people understand what Dementia is.” She ran the ad and mailed flyers.
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


  <!-- community ads -->
  <!-- advertising -->
  <br>
  <!-- talent acquisition -->
  <table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="top-buffer">
          <span class="h1">Talent Acquisition and Retention Tools</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="100">
          <a href="#s" target="_blank">
            <img src="#" style="width:100%;display:block;"></a>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="100">
          <span style="font-size:18px;display:inline-block; padding-top:10px;"><strong>Nurse Acquisition Video</strong></span>
          <br> Nurses are in high demand. As a company, we need to break through the stereotype of senior living to attract the best talent. This graphic links to a 2-minute video testimonial about why our nurses choose to grow careers at focusing
          on what we offer that hospitals and clinics don’t. Copy and paste this graphic, with the hyperlink, into your emails when you are recruiting nurse candidates.
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- text -->
  <!-- talent acquisition -->
  <br>
  <!-- new expert advice -->
  <table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="top-buffer">
          <span class="h1">New Expert Advice in the Resource Center</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-bottom:40px;">
          <span style="display:inline-block;">NEW articles sent from our <a href="#">Resource Center</a> on our website can help you help your local caregivers, prospects and families.  It’s easy to email the links. </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


  <!-- 1 -->
  <table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="345" class="column" style="height:100%;display:inline-block;">
          <img src="#" style="width:100%">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="345" class="column" style="padding-bottom:40px">
          <span style="padding-bottom:5px;"><strong><a href="#" target="_blank">A Conversation to have with your Mom that can’t wait</a></strong></span>
          <br>President, Judy Meleliat speaks candidly about how she approached “the talk” with her own 90 year old mother and offers tips.
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td width="345" class="column" style="height:100%;display:inline-block;">
          <img src="#" style="width:100%;display:block;">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="20">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="322" class="column" style="padding-bottom:40px;">
          <span style="display:inline-block; padding-bottom:5px;"><strong><a href="#" target="_blank">Types of assisted living</a></strong></span>
          <br> It’s a struggle to sort through all the information on “types” of senior living. This article helps to clarify the categories for a new family trying to understand.
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td width="345" class="column" style="height:100%;display:inline-block;">
          <img src="#" style="width:100%;display:block;">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="322" class="column" style="padding-bottom:40px;">
          <span style="display:inline-block; padding-bottom:5px;"><strong><a href="#" target="_blank">Is it time to think about assisted living?</a></strong><span>
           <br>
          What are the signs that your parent may need help?  Dr. Shirley Newell shows you what to look for. How are you holding up as a caregiver?
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td width="345" class="column" style="height:100%;display:inline-block;">
          <img src="#" style="width:100%;display:block;">
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td width="322" class="column" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
          <span style="display:inline-block; padding-bottom:5px;"><strong><a href="#" target="_blank"> Advice on paying for assisted living</a></strong></span>
          <br> Various ways to fund assisted living or memory care.
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- new expert advice -->

  <!-- epic speaker videos -->
  <table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="top-buffer">
          <span class="h1">EPIC Speaker Videos Released</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="345" style="height:100%;display:inline-block;margin-right:17px;" class="column">
          <img src="#" style="width:100%;display:block;">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="423" class="column" style="padding:20px;">The first packet of EPIC speaker DVD’s are in the General Manager’s hands for all-employee viewing. These videos aim to inspire with messages from world class athletes, politicians, physicians and speakers. This month we suggest you start with
          the uplifting message by world record setting swimmer, Diana Nyad recently seen on <em>Dancing with the Stars!</em>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- epic speaker videos -->

  <!-- upcoming events -->
  <table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="top-buffer">
          <span class="h1">Upcoming Events/Holidays</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table width="800" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <!-- <tr>
      <td width="100%" height="10">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
   -->
      <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="100">
          <span style="font-size:17px"><strong>
                May is: Physical Fitness Month&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;/&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Jewish American Heritage Month</strong></span>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <ul style="line-height: 150%; width: 582px;">

                    <li style="list-style-type:none; padding-left:10px;background-color:#ededed">May 10th - <span style="font-weight:300">Mother’s Day</span> </li>
                    <li style="list-style-type:none;padding-left:10px;">May 25th - <span style="font-weight:300">Memorial Day</span> </li>
                    <li style="list-style-type:none; padding-left:10px; background-color:#ededed">June 6th - <span style="font-weight:300">D-Day</span></li>
                    <li style="list-style-type:none;padding-left:10px;">June 14th - <span style="font-weight:300">Flag Day</span></li>
                    <li style="list-style-type:none; padding-left:10px; background-color:#ededed">June 21st - <span style="font-weight:300">Father’s Day</span></li>
                    <li style="list-style-type:none;padding-left:10px;">June 21st - <span style="font-weight:300">Alzheimer’s Association Longest day (click below for details)</span></li>
                  </ul>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="10">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <!-- alzheimer's -->
  <table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="10">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="100">
          <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" style="width:100%;display:block;"></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="10">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- alzheimer's -->

  <!-- prior -->
  <table width="800" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="10">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="100" style="padding:20px;">
          <span style="display:inline-block;padding-bottom:5px">
                Prior: If you are doing something in your community for the Longest Day, please email Director of Public Relations with a brief description of your plan as soon as you have it finalized.
                </span>
          <br> During your event, please take photos and send them to John so that we can post on social media and/or send to media to help spread the word. We’re proud of you and your residents. Let us brag.

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="10">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- prior-->
  <!-- upcoming events -->

  <!-- watch out for upcoming events-->
  <table width="800" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="10">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="top-buffer">
          <span class="h1" style="display:inline-block;line-height:120%;">WATCH FOR OUR MONTHLY MEDIA REPORT COMING SOON!</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="10">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- watch out for upcoming events-->


  <!-- footer -->
  <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="100%">
          <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
            <tbody>
              <!-- Spacing -->
              <tr>
                <td height="20" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- Spacing -->
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- end of footer -->

  <!-- end of background table-->
  </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I should specify that this is occurring on mobile only.

Comment: Maybe the page gets resized to fit on mobile screen instead of responsively adapting?

Comment: Just for fun, try it with em units instead and see if it reacts differently.  1em is approx. 16px.

Comment: A stupid idea - When I try this on Chrome and toggle the responsive view in dev console, I also get really small font... unless I check the "Zoom to fit available space" checkbox on top, which shows the device mockup in 1:1 (which, in turn, does not fit on the screen and shows the font in proper size). Please check whether your emulator doesn't do something similar by default

Comment: @Mike Good tip! I feel silly for not thinking of that. But it only half worked. Literally. It changed the base font size for the bottom half of the email. :/

Comment: Do you have additional pixel sizes declared elsewhere that may be overriding the em value?  That would be my first thought.  If you aren't already, try using something like Firebug to verify what CSS rules are impacting your element.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `16pt`? 16 point font and 16 pixel font are very different.

Comment: @Sander Yeah, I'm sure. The text remained the same illegible size on mobile when I changed it from (as a test) 16px to 20px. Seems like the only solution to this issue was to change the declaration to an em-based value. ...not quite sure why mobile email clients are unresponsive to the use of px-based font sizes, though.

Answer (score 1):

Line 42: `font-size: 16px!important;` needs a space between the x and !

but also, gmail won't read your style tag. that's why it's standard practice in email to put your font stylings in your `<td>` as well as an enclosed `<font>` tag with the `face` attribute as well as all the `style=""` CSS from the `<td>` (it helps with Windows Phone and some versions of Outlook that need a few reminders to render CSS)